# script/app to automatically click in an android app

Tags: android, click

I would like to automatically click at a certain location in an Android app every 0.1 seconds. Are there any apps or scripts that do not require root access that can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at those links:

[UI Tests using Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html#setup)

[Robotium](http://robotium.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I should have stated that the app I want to click in is a 3rd party app. I am also not an Android programmer. I am basically looking for an Android equivalent of AutoHotkey, though I only need to use the Click functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading up on [Espresso for Android](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html).

You can access UI components like this:

```
public void testClickButton() {
    // Type text and then press the button.
    onView( withId( R.id.button_main ) )
            .perform( typeText( SOME_STRING ), closeSoftKeyboard() );
    onView( withId( R.id.changeTextButton ) ).perform( click() );

    // assert that the text changes as expected
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I should have stated that the app I want to click in is a 3rd party app. I am also not an Android programmer. I am basically looking for an Android equivalent of AutoHotkey, though I only need to use the Click functionality.

Comment: I remember using AutoHotKey!  It's a pretty powerful tool.  For Android,  maybe you could use AirDroid https://www.airdroid.com/.  It will mirror your Android display for you on your PC - then you can break out your AutoHotKey script-fu.  :)

Comment: LOL I'm going to give that a try. Ingenious if it works :)